# Does $\sum \log(n)^n/n^{n/2}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the infinite series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{n/2}}$$
converge?

I'm not even sure where to go with this. I know there are a bunch of tests you can apply to find if a series converges or diverges, but I'm not sure where to start. Is there a trick to recognizing what test you should use?

Comment: Is it $\log n^n$ or $\log^n n$

Comment: In my paper it's not written either way. It looks like (ln n)^n.

Comment: Show that the summand is $O(n^{-\epsilon n})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I don't know what that means...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** We can rewrite the series as 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}}\right]^n
$$
With this in mind, we can conclude that since $\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}} \to 0$, the series will converge by the the ratio test (or root test).

To show that $\log(n)/n^{1/2} \to 0$, there are several working approaches.  The easiest is the substitution $n = t^2$ followed by L'Hôpital's rule. That is, 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\log(t^2)}{\sqrt{t^2}} = 2\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\log(t)}{t} = 2 \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1/t}{1} = 0
$$

Comment: It's not obvious to me that it goes to zero as you've written there. How did you determine that?

Comment: I've written in my answer a way that you can explicitly show it.  Intuitively, however, the notion to keep in mind is that "polynomials grow must faster than logs".

Comment: I would also say that, in general, if your sum is of the form
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty [f(n)]^n
$$
Then it is always worth it to try the ratio test or root test.

Comment: Note also that we could have applied L'Hôpital's rule directly rather than go through the $n = t^2$ substitution first.  However, my way looks nicer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For large $n$ we have
$$
\log n < \frac1{2} n^{1/2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{n/2}} < \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} < 1 
$$

Comment: Any pointers on what to do if you look at a series like this and you don't know where to start? Like, given some random series, what are the general steps you should use to try to figure out the convergence or divergence?

Comment: Chris, it is hard to say. In this one the trick is seeing that $\log n$ is increasing slower than any positive power of $n$. The rest is how you implement the idea. You can look @Omnomnomnom's solution, it has a different approach but the core idea is same. In general there are some fundamental series, and the problems you encounter are actually some versions of those fundamental ones. What I can suggest you is, you can select some 10-20 series problems and try to attack them. After a while you are going to be more comfortable seeing where/how to start a series problem. Sorry long comment.